# Lost in asynchronous function. Always get undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I just can't get my head around *asynchronous programming*! I need to update a node called `sToken` of an user which is the variable `userAux2`. But no matter how I try I always get **undefined**. I have read every question and tried many different ways, but I just don't know how to set `userAux2 = return snapshot.key;` (which btw, the snapshot prints ok in the console).

```js
  async loginUser(newEmail: string, newPassword: string, Company: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
    var userAux2: string;
    await this.getCurrentUserID(newEmail, Company).then((userAux) => {
      userAux2 = userAux;
    });   

    console.log('userAux2 ==============>>>> ' + userAux2); //this one is undefined

    await this.updateToken(userAux2, Company).then(() => {
      return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword);   
    }); 
  }

// Get ID of Single User
  async getCurrentUserID(Email: string, Company: string): Promise<any>{
    var ref = this.db.database.ref(`companies/${Company}`);
    ref.child("users")
    .orderByChild("sEmail")
    .equalTo(Email)
    .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log('snapshot.key = ' + snapshot.key); 
        return snapshot.key;
    });
 }  

 async updateToken(userAux: string, Company: string){
    var Token1: string;
    Token1 = 'hola';

        var tokenData = {
          sToken: Token1
        };
          console.log('userAux = -------------- ' + userAux);
          var updates = {};
          updates['/companies/' + Company + '/users/' + userAux] = tokenData;

          return this.db.database.ref().update(updates);           
  }
```

Comment: the variable is always undefiend because the line is executed before the async. move the `console.log` into the async callback and it will be fine

Comment: Thanks, but still the same thing... =/

Comment: your first two async functions `loginUser` and  `getCurrentUserID` don't return anything ... so, that's the same as returning undefined

Comment: `var userAux2: string; await this.getCurrentUserID(newEmail, Company).then((userAux) => {
      userAux2 = userAux;
    });` is just poorly written version of `var userAux2: string = await this.getCurrentUserID(newEmail, Company);`

Comment: but my function is returning  return snapshot.key;, Is that wrong?